# How can I calculate min, max and average values from random numbers?

Tags: php, random, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<p>Exercise 5:</p>";

echo "Numbers: ";

$random = 0;

while ($random < 10) {
    $rand = rand(2, 80);
    echo "$rand";

    $random = $random + 1;

    if ($random < 10) {
     echo ", ";
    };
}

echo "<br><br>Min value: <br>";
echo "Max value: <br>";
echo "Average value: <br>";
?>
```

How can I calculate the min, max and average value of the 10 numbers?

`$min = min($rand)` doesn't work... 
`$max = max($rand)` doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rand` is a single value, minimum of a single value is irrelevant. Min takes an array as parameter (or several values), so save your values in an array, e.g. like this.

```
$array = array();

while($random < 10) {
    $rand = rand(2, 80);
    $array[] = $rand;
    $random++; // short for random = random + 1
}

echo min($array);
```

Works also with max.

Moreover, average = sum / count, you have [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and  [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function in PHP, I let you figure out how to do that.

**Edit**: Augustin is right about division by zero. Consider adding a condition when making a division by a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured out a solution that works for me

Answer (score 0):

One solutions thinking in division by zero could be:

```
$random = 0;
$numbers = array();
while ($random < 10) {
    $rand = rand(2, 80);
    echo "$rand";

    $numbers[] = $rand;

   $random ++;
}

$min = min($numbers);
$max = max($numbers);
if($totalNumbers = count($numbers) > 0) {
    $average = array_sum($numbers) / count($numbers);
}else{
    $average = 0;
}


echo "<br><br>Min value: $min <br>";
echo "Max value: $max <br>";
echo "Average value: $average <br>";
```

I don't understand why min or max doesn't work, but in this case, you could make a custom max min function:

```
function customMaxMin($numbers)
{

    $max = 0;
    $min = 0;

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {

        $max = $number;
        $min = $number;

        if ($max > $number) {
            $max = $number;
        }
        if ($min < $number) {
            $min = $number;
        }

    }


    return array('max' => $max, 'min' => $min);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to find a solution